# Convert to comments with unattached owners breaks conversion wrongly

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderation, convert-to-comment

When using the Convert To Comments mod tool on a post with child comments, of which the child comments have unattached users (and in this case the post had an attached owner) the unattached children break the conversion.

**Example post structure** (poor example but simple to follow, post ids are contrived for the purposes of an example)

```
Q: PostId 5001 - attached owner

A: PostId 5004 - attached owner
   C: - unattached owner
   C: - unattached owner
   C: - unattached owner
   C: - attached owner (author of 5004)

Convert To Comment
  Attach to Post?
    [5001]
    [X] convert child comments?
```

When I do this, it only copies 5004, and none of the C, onto 5001. I would expect it to copy the C and just never attach them to an owner, if it can't track the owners for in the future.

Comment: seems this bug is still alive and kicking, looking at it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in build 2013.7.19.1249 (meta), 2013.7.19.874 (sites)